# Elasticsearch: transform date with groovy script

Tags: groovy, elasticsearch

i have the following (simplified) mapping:

```
{
  "event_date": {
    "_source": { "enabled": true },
    "_all": { "enabled": true },
    "dynamic": "strict",
    "properties": {
      "start_date_time": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "dateOptionalTime"
      },
      "start_date_day": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "dateOptionalTime",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The indexed objects will look like this:

```
{
  "start_date_time": "2017-05-08T18:23:45+0200"
}
```

The property `start_date_day` should always contain the same date, but with the time set to 00:00:00. In the example above `start_date_day` must be "2017-05-08T00:00:00+0200".

I think,it is possible to achieve this with a [transform mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-transform.html) and a groovy script, but my developed groovy code did not work in the elasticsearch-context and I am not that familiar with the groovy language.

Maybe someone has an idea on how to solve this?

Comment: 1) Are you sure you want to keep the timezone at the end? It doesn't make sense without the hours. 2) do you absolutely need to keep the hour part even if it is `00:00:00`, i.e. would you also accept to simply have `"start_date_time": "2017-05-08"`?

Comment: I need both, the exact date including the date and time (start_date_time) and I need the date without the time ((start_date_day). But, the indexing date will just contain the start_date_time. Therefore, i want to make a transformation to store the date without the time in a field named "start_date_day".

Comment: But my question was whether for you and your application logic "2017-05-08" and "2017-05-08T00:00:00+0200" would be equivalent or not? i.e. since you don't need the hour part in the `start_date_day` field, why store it at all with 00:00:00`?

Comment: Also, i do not care about the timezone. start_date_day could also be formatted like "yyyy-MM-dd". The important part is, that the time will be cut off

Comment: There we go! Exactly what I want to know

Comment: The use case is: I want to sort a list of documents by their dates. When two documents "are on the same day", the should be sorted by another field. This requirement cannot be fulfilled with start_date_time, because elasticsearch will only distinguish between the same "second" of the date, not the same "day". Therefore, I need a less precise date, ergo "start_date_day"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is doable, for testing/running you might need to turn on `script.groovy.sandbox.enabled: true` in `../conf/elasticsearch.yml` first.

```
PUT datetest/
{
    "mappings": {
        "event_date": {
            "_source": { "enabled": true },
            "_all": { "enabled": true },
            "dynamic": "strict",
            "transform" : {
                "script" : "ctx._source['start_date_day'] = new Date().parse(\"yyyy-MM-dd\", ctx._source['start_date_time']).format(\"yyyy-MM-dd\");",
                "lang": "groovy"
            },
            "properties": {
                "start_date_time": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                },
                "start_date_day": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "dateOptionalTime",
                    "index": "not_analyzed",
                    "store": "yes"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample data:

```
PUT /datetest/event_date/1
{
  "start_date_time": "2017-05-08T18:23:45+0200"
}
```

Sample output:

```
GET /datetest/event_date/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "fields": ["start_date_time","start_date_day"]
}

{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "datetest",
            "_type": "event_date",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "fields": {
               "start_date_day": [
                  "2017-05-08T00:00:00.000Z"
               ],
               "start_date_time": [
                  "2017-05-08T18:23:45+0200"
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes! Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much!!! 

I needed to make s small change in the mappings file, to get this working. I got a syntax error when inserting the mapping, so i changed the escaped double quotes to single quotes...

Comment: no problem, glad to be of help :-) you can mark this as the answer if you dont have any more questions

Comment: another question to this: Is there a way,to assign multi-fields in groovy scripts? i would like to place the property `start_date_day` as  sub-field of `start_date_time`, like in the following mapping:

    "start_date_time": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "dateOptionalTime",
        "fields": {
            "start_date_day": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "dateOptionalTime",
                "store": true
            }
        }
    }
but `ctx._source['start_date_time']['start_date_day']` and ctx._source['start_date_time.start_date_day'] did not work

Comment: @Samir I don't really see how you want to do it, `start_date_time` is just a `date` property, it cannot have nested fields. You could wrap it all in an object that has `start_date_time` as a field and the other one as a nested object but it seems pointless ;-)

Comment: @Samir, you should ask another question ;) @Mateusz Dymczyk multi-fields are [definitely possible](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html#_multi_fields_3) on a `date` field (using `"fields":{...}`), any core types actually, just not `object` and `nested`

Answer (score 1):

i think it is the format which isn't good. "date" seems to be MM/DD/YYYY and only this. If you want the time you need datetime format. 
I have found this link which can help you : [Elastic date format](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html)

You can try to change type "date" to "basic_date_time".

Comment: The dates are always formatted in ISO8601, so the date string will always be "2017-05-08T18:23:45+0200". I could specify another format like "basic_date_time", but then inserting the date string will lead to the following error:

`MapperParsingException[failed to parse date field [2017-06-07T05:03:25+0200], tried both date format [basic_date_time], and timestamp number with locale []]; nested:  
   IllegalArgumentException[Invalid format: \"2017-06-07T05:03:25+0200\" is malformed at \"-06-07T05:03:25+0200\"]`

Not the date format is the problem.I want to change the precision the date is stored

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, since you don't need the hour part, you can simply define the mapping for the `start_date_day` field using the [`date` format](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html) and use the following `transform` like this:

```
{
  "event_date": {
    "_source": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "_all": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "dynamic": "strict",
    "transform": {
      "script": "ctx._source['start_date_day'] = ctx._source['start_date_time'].split('T')[0]",
      "lang": "groovy"
    },
    "properties": {
      "start_date_time": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "dateOptionalTime"
      },
      "start_date_day": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "date",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

ES will only store the date part and leave the hours and timezone out.

However, you should note that when using `transform`, the original source is stored without modification, the result of the transform will be indexed though, and hence searchable.

Comment: actually you can store `start_date_day` too

Comment: Thx @MateuszDymczyk. Learn something new everyday ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort! This answer is also right, but Mateusz' answer is a little bit more generic due to the fact, that the resulting date is parsed as a Date-object and returned in the desired format. With this, i can define the precision of the date myself. 

Thank you!!!

Comment: Absolutely, glad you found your answer ;)